# Resume JSON Streaming after break in Jackson

Tags: json, jackson

Is there a way to resume streaming of JSON persisted to a file after a restart ?

i.e, If I was using JsonGenerator to stream array elements (records) and application fails in middle of streaming, is there a approach to rebuild the context (JsonWriteContext) upon application restart ?

Comment: Unlikely you can do that. It's easier to restart serialization from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as of Jackson 1.9.4, the context cannot be rebuilt. Got it confirmed from Tatu Saloranta
see the mailing list discussion:

http://markmail.org/message/mhx64nibm5ihi76i?q=list:org%2Ecodehaus%2Ejackson+JsonWriteContext#query:list%3Aorg.codehaus.jackson%20JsonWriteContext+page:1+mid:mhx64nibm5ihi76i+state:results